# Visual Studio Code for Mac "undefined symbols for architecture"

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I am just starting to code in c++ and I am choosing to use visual studio code for mac as my ide. I have g++ installed in my terminal and the Microsoft c/c++ and code runner extensions installed in visual studio. I have successfully compiled and ran a hello world .cpp file. The issue is when I created a new .cpp file, whenever I try and run any program (even the same program that previously worked) I am now getting this error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_main", referenced from:
     implicit entry/start for main executable
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Does anyone know how to fix this so that in the future I can just create a new .cpp file and not have to deal with this issue? Thank you.

here is the program I am trying to run:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    cout << "Hello World!" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Could you include the program you are trying to run in your question?

Comment: added code to the orginal post

Comment: maybe you have installed the wrong version of visual studio code, the 32 bit one, while you probably need the x64.

Comment: nope, just checked and it says x64 version

Comment: You wrote that *I have successfully compiled and ran a hello world .cpp file*, but then propose a hello world file as source of linker errors. What is the name of the .cpp file in question?

Comment: So when I first wrote his program, I was able to execute it to output hello world as intended, but when I created a new file, this error message started appearing, so to check and make sure it wasnt the code, I copied and pasted this code listed and it gives me the same error message.

Comment: and how did you name all these files?